# Checking each item in IEnumerable<List<int>>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

At the moment I have some code like below which based on a NoOfRows properties returns whether all data has been entered into list(s):

```
switch (NoOfRows)
            {
                case 1:
                    return InputList1.Any();
                case 2:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any();
                case 3:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any();
                case 4:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any();
                case 5:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any();
                case 6:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any() && InputList6.Any();
                case 7:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any() && InputList6.Any() && InputList7.Any();
                case 8:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any() && InputList6.Any() && InputList7.Any() && InputList8.Any();
                case 9:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any() && InputList6.Any() && InputList7.Any() && InputList8.Any() && InputList9.Any();
                case 10:
                    return InputList1.Any() && InputList2.Any() && InputList3.Any() && InputList4.Any() && InputList5.Any() && InputList6.Any() && InputList7.Any() && InputList8.Any() && InputList9.Any() && InputList10.Any();
                default:
                    return false;
            }
```

I'm thinking it might be better to refactor this code and have an `List<List<int>> or a Dictionary<int,List<int>>` but how would I do the above to return whether each list in the collection has something in it?

```
List<List<int>> values = new List<List<int>>(){InputList1, InputList2 ... InputList10};
var lists = values.Take(NoOfRows);
lists.. //check each item and return value of Any for each one
```

Comment: Are you saying you just want to check that every list in the collection of lists is non-empty?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Yes, just trying to refactor the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

having nested lists can work well. you might want to look into the use of [selectmany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

but I think the code you want is something like:

```
var nested = new List<List<int>>();
// put data in it

nested.All((inner) => inner.Any());
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to know if any sub-list is empty, try this:

```
var values = new List<List<int>>();  // create and load up...

...

// returns true if any sub-list is EMPTY
var isAnyEmpty = values.Any(l => !l.Any());
```

This will check if there exists any list in the list of lists that does not have an item.

However, if you want the **indexes** of those sub-lists that are empty, you can just store the results of the Any() on all:

```
// will return a lists of bools for Any() applied to each sub-list
var listStates = values.Select(l => l.Any()).ToList();
```

Then, the index of any result where the value is `false` will be a list without any items.  Or, alternatively, you could use the special form of `Select` that pass along indexes directly.

Comment: Wouldn't that last line be better as `var listStates = values.Where(l => !l.Any()).ToList();`? Why return a bunch of indexes when you can return the empty lists themselves?

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Point taken, though of course it depends on what the OP wants, really.  They can return true/false, the references, or the indexes, whichever is most useful to them.

Comment: This is not working as expected:  private bool AllExpectedDataReceived()
        {
            var Lists = InputLists.Take(NoOfRows);

            return Lists.Any(x => x.Any());
        }

Comment: @Jon: how do you mean? the statement you are showing is missing the `!` from my code snippet, it should be x => !x.Any(), it looks like your forgot the `!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listoflists = new List<List<int>>;
bool allNonEmpty = listoflists.All(list => list.Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this:

```
    bool ContainsEmptyCollection(IEnumerable<List<int>> collections)
    {
        foreach (var collection in collections)
        {
            if (collection.Count == 0)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
        List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
        bool anyNonEmpty = list.Any(x => x.Any());
```